# ServerSocket - Handling status request

Tags: java, network-programming, serversocket

I have a ServerSocket listening on a port and clients connect to it and provide functional requests implemented as Object streams. For each request received, got a socket and read from it like this

```
new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
...
```

This works fine.

Now I want to handle a plain socket connection from client for the sake of status of the ServerSocket. For this I just opened a `Socket` and if it is successful, assert it is Up else Down. I don't want to implement this status request using Object stream.

The above Server code results in `java.io.EOFException` from ObjectInputStream as there is no object stream possible.

What is the practice to handle status request of the ServerSocket.

Comment: Err, make up your mind? Don't create an ObjectInoutStream until you know you need one? Use it for all requests? Make a decision?

Comment: I think I can get an InputStream with out any problem for both kind of requests, but  after that How to decide it is a plain request or a request with Object stream, without getting OpjectInputStream.